# what documentation describe what are passed into express app.METHOD callback arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I am noob with javascript and nodejs, and cannot get my head around callback function sometime. What I found most confusing is to find what arguments (or should it be called parameters?) is passed into a callback function.

consider the following example

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to homepage');
});
```

If I understand right, I can change what the argument name within the function to something else (e.g. a,b instead of req,res) and it will still contain the request and response object respectively.

```
app.get('/', function (a, b) {
  b.send('GET request to homepage');
});
```

that is because app.get method/function defined its second argument to be a callback function, and what is going to pass into that callback function as argument, right?

If the above is true, I just couldn't find the documentation in the Express API document describing what is pass into callback function arguments for that method/function. In fact, I can hardly find documents describing what is passed into callback for a lot of other methods/functions. Where can I find this information? Am I looking at the wrong piece of information because I messed up with some terminology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who're visiting this 3 yrs old question hoping for the answer (as I did),
I hope answer below enlightens your mood ;)

- Average callback(middleware functions) have three arguments (i.e. req, res, next)

  - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html
- Error callback has special form; It has four arguments.

  - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers

> **Writing error handlers**
>   Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, ***except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three***: (err, req, res, next). For example:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

If you are using TypeScript for your Express API, you need to explicitly type all the parameters, or the compiler will implicitly type the params to Any and crash during transpilation.

```
app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There documentation you are looking for is here

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: I am sorry but I failed to see how the documents provided actually answer my questions. These documents explain the properties and method the request and response objects have. What I asked however is what parameters/arguments are passed into the methods/function/API callback that express provided.

Comment: @NickLi these ARE the parameters that express provides to route callback functions

Comment: in the simple case of having two parameters in route method then yes. But I have seen cases where there are 3 parameters (req,res,next) and 4 (err, req, res, next), does it take 5,6 or 7 parameters? and what will be passed in those cases? My question is if there are documents about such information? (Thank you for your help)

Comment: you should read the entire thing (doc page.. the whole of it) instead of asking stackoverflow to recite it for you

Comment: I am sorry but isn't it the whole point of stackoverflow? To ask questions when one cannot find the answers. The point is I READ through the documentation but I cannot find the information, and the link you send does not contain the information I need (if it does then my deepest apology). for example, [router.param documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.param) has clearly stated what the callback function parameters will be, but not for router.METHOD or router.all, which is what I am asking.